# Windows command line command to print an HTML file as a pdf file with support of Latex Equation

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, command-line, latex

I have HTML files containing latex equations & their referencing as shown in screenshot attached...
[image]

If I try to print this file as PDF from the browser itself, using this dialog...
[image]

Now the generated pdf file is exactly the same as HTML with well formatted Latex Equations & their cross-referencing as shown below...
[image]

I need to automate this (printing HTML to PDF file step) through command line command to replicate exactly same output (as browser print option). I tried below command...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="E:\pdfs\PipeFlow.pdf" "D:\Repos\PipeFlow.html"
```

But it neither formats the Latex equations well, nor their cross-referencing as shown below...
[image]

Can I  get the correct command line command to get well formatted Latex equations & their referencing, exactly as we get from browser print option? Thank you.